# Product of a normal subgroup with a subgroup generated by two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose that $N\unlhd G$ and $A,B \leq G$. I want to show that $\langle A, B\rangle N = \langle AN, BN\rangle$.

Clearly, $AN \leq \langle A, B\rangle N$ and $BN \leq \langle A, B\rangle N$. Since the subgroup $\langle AN, BN\rangle$ is defined to be the smallest subgroup containing $AN$ and $BN$, then $\langle AN, BN\rangle \subseteq \langle A, B\rangle N$

I'm not sure how to get the other inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the converse, $A \le AN$ and $B \le BN$ implies that $\langle A, B \rangle \le \langle AN, BN \rangle$, so that we have $\langle A, B \rangle N \le \langle AN, BN \rangle N = \langle AN, BN \rangle$ (since $N \le \langle AN, BN \rangle$).

Answer (score 3):

The subgroup $\left<A,B\right>N$ is generated by elements of the form $an$ and $bn^{\prime}$ with $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $n,n^{\prime}\in N$. All of these are in $\left<AN,BN\right>$. This is the other inclusion and is shown as follows.

A given element of $\left<A,B\right>N$ can be given as $g_1\cdot g_2\cdots g_k\cdot n$, where the $g_i's$ alternate between belonging to $A$ or $B$, and $n\in N$. Since $1\in N$, $$g_1\cdot g_2\cdots g_k\cdot n=(g_11)\cdot (g_21)\cdots (g_k\cdot n)$$ has the desired form.

Comment: I'm having a problem in showing that the elements of $\langle A, B\rangle N$ are of the form $an$ and $bn'$. For instance if $aba\in \langle A, B\rangle $ and $n\in N$ then I'm not sure how I would be able to get it in the required form

Comment: Apparently, the normality of $N$ is unnecessary for this inclusion. I think it is only used so that the sets involved are subgroups of $G$.

Comment: @J.DavidTaylor I'd suggest removing the initial part of the answer and keeping only the edit. That *is* the proof, and the initial part only serves to obscure it.

Comment: Thanks I really understand your reasoning